# low frequency ripple current RMS amps and temperature rise in MLCC

Tags: temperature, ripple, ceramic, mlcc

Manufacturers only specify this metric of 0.1, 0.5 and 1MHz.

Is there any way to calculate / estimate the temperature rise in these capacitors for much lower frequencies, in the Hz range, based on certain RMS amperage value ?

Comment: What do these "RMS amperage" numbers *mean*? How are they measured?

Comment: @Hearth RMS amperage mean 'root mean square' amperage  - https://masteringelectronicsdesign.com/how-to-derive-the-rms-value-of-pulse-and-square-waveforms/. They were not measured but calculated from a simulated waveform.

Comment: I know very well what RMS amperage means. I'm asking what you're doing with these frequencies associated with them--are these peaks from the Fourier-domain representation of the data (as you would measure with a spectrum analyzer) or are they measured by integrating time-domain data filtered to different bandwidths, or what?

Comment: Exactly what value of capacitor are you using at such frequencies? 220mA at 2Hz in the largest single-chip MLCC I can think of (say 100uF) is 175V...

Comment: @Hearth they are picked up from time domain via approximating segments / shapes.

Comment: @Tim I need them to withstand 150V, those datapoints are for 1uF @ 100V MLCC, but I think .22uF @ 250V will be better (making the datapoints of somewhat less amp @ same frequencies)

Comment: @kellogs If these are 1 μF capacitors, your numbers don't make any sense. Those RMS currents correspond to thousands of volts, far more than your 100 V rating or 150 V target.

Comment: Uh oh... no ESR in my simulation. Maybe I can find a model for this cap online

Comment: @kellogs Show us a schematic of your simulation, please. I'd like to see what exactly is forcing this much current into the capacitors--it could be your model of the stuff *around* the capacitor is more of a problem than the model of the capacitor itself--the ESR of MLCCs is usually small enough to be mostly irrelevant, and the ESL definitely is at such low frequencies.

Comment: @Hearth added; not much difference between model cap and standard cap indeed

Comment: That's a ~200us pulse, how the heck did you get Hz out of that?

Comment: @TimWilliams check out the PWL source